# Using Schema.org for freelancer portfolio page

Tags: schema.org

I just launched my personal website to advertise my services for front-end web development and digital art.

I'm looking into adding Schema.org structured data to the page but cannot find a list of organization/person types to use for a freelance/contractor.

Any insight on what Schema.org types I might want to include on my site for my specific niche?

Comment: Same problem here. I was thinking of using [ProfessionalService](https://schema.org/ProfessionalService) schema type but it is deprecated. I'll use the [Corporation](https://schema.org/Corporation) schema as suggested in the answers. Please be careful about the served area (`areaServed` property), especially if you work remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use http://schema.org/Person for this. You might want to consider http://schema.org/Corporation as well. Depending on how you want to market yourself. I.E. freelancer vs company.

Comment: Thank you, I think that confirms my suspicions. I'll look into structuring this under Person with jobTitle etc.
Thanks again.